# Is there an ideal shape for minimizing each type of drag at subsonic, transonic, and supersonic speeds?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, aerodynamics

The [Sears-Haack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sears%E2%80%93Haack_body) body minimizes theoretical wave drag in supersonic flow on a body of a given length and volume. Are there shapes that minimize wave drag, viscous drag, turbulent drag, and pressure drag in all different regimes of flow?

Comment: There are a few interesting shapes at supersonic speeds. You can greatly reduce drag, and the sonic boom at the same time. But they don't produce lift. Hence: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190197/sci-fi-story-about-supersonic-blimp

Comment: [Is this what you were talking about?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busemann_biplane)

Comment: This video discusses the changes the SR-71 engine goes through as it speeds from $0$ to Mach $3.2$ There is much more to it than drag. [The Insane Engineering of the SR-71 Blackbird](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hYSnyVLmGE)